# "map extent" in Ionic

Tags: dictionary, ionic-framework

I've a problem with Ionic and OpenLayers: starting from my Angular component (that works well), when I do map.getView().fit(myExtent) inside a Ionic Component the result isn't a good fit, but it seems a wrong zoom calculation. Do you think can be a "resolution" and/or pixel dimension problem?

in component

```
let myExtent = mylayer.getSource().getExtent();
//Angular component and Ionic component on console.log write the same values!

myMap.getView().fit(myExtent);
//in Angular it works correct, in Ionic not
```

in HTML

```
<div class="map" id="map"></div>
```

in css

```
.map{
height:300px;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you try to pass the size?, something like this,
`mapSize = myMap.getSize();
myMap.getView().fit(myExtent, {size: mapSize});`